# Forcing LINQ to use a Stored Procedure when accessing a Database

Tags: linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I've done some searches (over the web and SO) but so far have been unable to find something that directly answer this:

*Is there anyway to **force** L2S to use a Stored Procedure when acessing a Database?*

This is different from simply using SPROC's with L2S: The thing is, I'm relying on LINQ to lazy load elements by accessing then through the generated "Child Property". If I use a SPROC to retrieve the elements of one table, map then to an entity in LINQ, and then access a child property, I believe that LINQ will retrieve the register from the DB using dynamic sql, which goes against my purpose.

---

**UPDATE:**

Sorry if the text above isn't clear. What I really want is something that is like the "Default Methods" for Update, Insert and Delete, however, to Select. I want every access to be done through a SPROC, but I want to use `Child Property`.

Just so you don't think I'm crazy, the thing is that my DAL is build using child properties and I was accessing the database through L2S using dynamic SQL, but last week the client has told me that all database access must be done through SPROCS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't believe that there is a switch or setting that out of the box and automagically would map to using t sprocs the way you are describing. But there is now reason why you couldn't alter the generated DBML file to do what you want. If I had two related tables, a Catalog table and CatalogItem tables, the Linq2SQL generator will naturally give me a property of CatalogItems on Catalog, code like:

```
private EntitySet<shelf_myndr_Previews_CatalogItem> _shelf_myndr_Previews_CatalogItems;

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="CatalogItem", Storage="_CatalogItems", ThisKey="Id", OtherKey="CatalogId")]
public EntitySet<CatalogItem> CatalogItems
    {
        get
        {
            return this._CatalogItems;
                            //replace this line with a sproc call that ultimately
                            //returns the expected type
        }
        set
        {
            this._CatalogItems.Assign(value);
                            //replace this line with a sproc call that ultimately
                            //does a save operation
        }
    }
```

There is nothing stopping you from changing that code to be sproc calls there. It'd be some effort for larger applications and I'd be sure that you be getting the benefit from it that you think you would.

Comment: +1 because it is probably the only way to do it, but it's not pretty.  This is generated code, so you would have to be careful not to overwrite it with a regen of the DBML.

Comment: nope, not pretty, but the DBML was designed to be edited in this manner. Maybe not this purpose. And yep, have to be careful of regens, but its what you have source control for, right?

Comment: The system is small; The refactoring is way worse if I have to do it at the DAL level, so I guess this is the best way. Thanks, I will check it out.

Comment: I tried doing it, but there is one problem, I don't have access to the DataContext, without which I cannot call the SPROC. Any ideas?

Comment: In for a penny, in for a pound. if you are already altering the behaviour of the Linq2SQL objects to support returning sproc results, why not alter the constructors to take a DataContext as a parameter? Though at this point, not knowing more about your project, I think you may be coming dangerously close to dig a great big hole for yourself. Have you considered other ideas, like a Repository pattern? You could build your business objects/entities/relationships and internally you could use L2SQL and make sure you are only calling sprocs. I'd be worried about the maintainance nightmare.

Comment: @Jonathan: Thanks to the gods, I already have a repository pattern. When I began the project, I wasn't quite acquainted with EF, so I built a Repository that would extract data objects and create instances from a model. Thing is, the class that converted the data objects relied on Relationship Properties. But I will change the whole code now in order not to, like you said, turn this into a maintainance nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

How about loading the child entities using the partial OnLoaded() method in the parent entity? That would allow you to avoid messing with generated code.  Of course it would no longer be a lazy load, but it's a simple way to do it.

**For example:**

```
public partial class Supplier
{
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

    partial void OnLoaded()
    {
        // GetProductsBySupplierId is the SP dragged into your dbml designer
        Products = dataContext.GetProductsBySupplierId(this.Id).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm mixing your idea with Jonathan's one, creating a customized property as a partial class, but how do I access the dataContext (like you did above)? It seems like I don't have access to it.

Comment: Different systems provide access to the current context in different ways. You'll have to decide how to do it in yours (and it helps to do it early in the design process so I'd recommend figuring that out as soon as you can).  Without knowing what type of app you're working on and what your existing DAL is (it sounds like you have some constraints), I'm afraid I can't do much more than provide some resources.  Rick Strahl's article is good: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/246222.aspx And see Pt 3 of NerdDinner for the repository pattern: http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm

Answer (score 0):

Call your stored procedure this way:

[image]

Where `GetProductsByCategoryName` is the name of your stored procedure.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx

Comment: Harvey, thanks for the reply. My problem is this, say that your `Product` entity had a column called "SupplierId", which is FK to a table called "Suppliers" which maps to an Entity called `Supplier` and a `Child Property` called "Supplier", . With native LINQ, I'd just go `product.Supplier.Name` to retrieve the name of the related supplier. However, I want access to the Suppliers table to be done through the use of a SPROC. Is it possible?